# Why is the performance of my app perfectly fine on desktop but it messes up on phone using ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, performance

Someone asked me to create a website for his sportsclub, I decided it try and make this webpage in ReactJs.

https://complexbjj-2a19b.firebaseapp.com/ this is the outcome, looks pretty and 
 works well on desktop.

It's pretty responsive layout wise.

So I was pretty happy untill I decided to build and deploy for production.

Sadly I found out that the webpage wasn't optimised for phones at all, leaving random blank spaces.

I tried allot of things, changing to PureComponents, Using React.memo.., etc etc.

Nothing seems to help, so now I'm here after hours & hours of trying to find a solution with my hands in my hair.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Comment: What framework are u using? is it bootstrap css?

Comment: I'm Using ReactJS & Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `Google Chrome` browser installed on your machine, you can try auditing your app in the inspector `Audits` tab (here is the [doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse)). That could help you spot possible improvements.

Comment: I've done multiple audits already, performance wise it was allot worse in terms of score.. i've also used this website https://gtmetrix.com/. the feedback from this website basicly tells me i need some sort of better caching in place?

Comment: I have tried to make a performance audit, and it made my Lighthouse crash...:)

Comment: I have tried running a test on WebPageTest, here is the result: https://webpagetest.org/result/191013_BG_27baffc6e150eb491a6231dd9ffbde0a/

Comment: Maybe consider using smaller image files on smaller screen devices ?

Comment: Also, the hash in your assets filename is a `content hash` ?

Comment: I used  create-react-app to build my initial project, where can i find content hash?

Comment: Also i made a media-query to add lower resolution images already, still no difference..